I want multiple processes writing .gcda data on multiple files
I have compiled my c source files using --coverage. I have a exe which runs this c source files. Usually I open one instance of this exe and generate coverage data but now I want to open 2 instances of this exe and run 2 different tests on theses instances. I want coverage of these tests simultaneously to improve my execution time.
The c source exe runs on ports. Every instance gets new port assigned to it. The test communicates with my execution using ports. I want to create coverage data based on ports.
How can I do this?
I have created multiple copies (based on ports) of the object folder where my .o, .gcda files are.
